# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sized' from 'collections'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I am trying to use one package that somebody developed on GitHub called PyLipid.
The first parts of the code are importing various packages, but I am continuously getting this error, showed bellow:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pylipid
import collections 
from pylipid.api import LipidInteraction
# print(pylipid.__version__) # make sure pylipid version is later than 1.4

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import pylipid
      3 import collections 
----> 4 from pylipid.api import LipidInteraction

File ~/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pylipid/api/__init__.py:32, in <module>
      1 ##############################################################################
      2 # PyLipID: A python module for analysing protein-lipid interactions
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     15 ##############################################################################
     17 r"""
     18 PyLipID class
     19 =============
   (...)
     29 
     30 """
---> 32 from .api import LipidInteraction

File ~/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pylipid/api/api.py:30, in <module>
     28 import pandas as pd
     29 from tqdm import trange, tqdm
---> 30 from p_tqdm import p_map
     31 from ..func import cal_contact_residues
     32 from ..func import Duration

File ~/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/p_tqdm/__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from p_tqdm.p_tqdm import p_map, p_imap, p_umap, p_uimap, t_map, t_imap
      3 __all__ = [
      4     'p_map',
      5     'p_imap',
   (...)
      9     't_imap'
     10 ]

File ~/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/p_tqdm/p_tqdm.py:11, in <module>
      1 """Map functions with tqdm progress bars for parallel and sequential processing.
      2 
      3 p_map: Performs a parallel ordered map.
   (...)
      8 t_imap: Returns an iterator for a sequential map.
      9 """
---> 11 from collections import Sized
     12 from typing import Any, Callable, Generator, Iterable, List
     14 from pathos.helpers import cpu_count

ImportError: cannot import name 'Sized' from 'collections' (/home/srdjanm/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this error? I have also posted the question on the webpage in github but it might take a while for someone to respond, also this seems to me like a more general problem. Is this the package or "python version" related issue?

Comment: It should be `from collections.abc import Sized` but maybe the library needs more updates to work.

Comment: What is your purpose with the lib? using it or developing it? If using is considered then you can just pip3 install it. and it should be collections.abc.Sized.

Comment: I wish to use it, but I think this library is too old and nobody has updated it for python 3 onwards. I'll check up on it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to modify one line in the library to it works. It was created a pull request in [github of p_tqdm library](https://github.com/swansonk14/p_tqdm/pull/42)


In file `~/miniconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.10/site-packages/p_tqdm/p_tqdm.py` modify line `11` from

```
from collections import Sized
```

to

```
from collections.abc import Sized
```